# Overlaying Loading Image on Google Maps while Waiting for Loading Markers

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can someone let me know if it is possible to Load a Loading image like below on the map while waiting for loading a big amount of Markers.
I couldn't find any sample on Goggle for this. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Well how do you load your markers?

Comment: Hi MrUpsidown, and thanks for your reply.I am using a Ajax calling by loading data from json. Here is simple example of what I was doing.Please be informed that I just load two markers for example but it can be more than 200 http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/J2B3K/10/

Comment: Perhaps [ProgressBar](http://www.basicslabs.com/Projects/progressBar/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading screen for Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502478/loading-screen-for-google-maps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using jQuery so you can check the jQuery.ajax() documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can use **beforeSend**, **success** and **complete**

```
$.ajax({

    url : "file.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSend : function() {

        // Show loading DIV
    },
    success : function() {

        // Plot markers
    },   
    complete : function() {

        // Hide loading DIV
    }
});
```